# Getting job owner from Databricks CLI

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-workflows

I'm trying to obtain the owner of a list of jobs on databricks using CLI. The issue is, the command `databricks jobs list` doesn't have any information related with that, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Permissions API for that. Specifically the [Get Job Permissions Levels API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/permissions.html#operation/get-jobs-permission-levels). Just do a GET request against endpoint `https://<databricks-instance>/api/2.0/preview/permissions/jobs/{job_id}/permissionLevels` - replace `{job_id}` with actual Job ID

Comment: Quick question on above solution . can we update the owner of the job through Rest API call ? Please confirm .